# When to use JFrame, JLabel, and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have been, for a long time, wondering when to use JFrame and JPanel. I was told by textbook, in-person, and via internet search some reasons, but of course, it took me looking at the Java documentation to figure out that a JPanel has the paintComponent(Graphics); method, which allows you to specify what to do to the object itself, unlike JFrame. Also, JPanels are nestable, allowing for more complex graphics than you could achieve with just one container. I also stumbled upon the fact that a JLabel is also a container. (It even has a freaking layout!) Now my question is: when should I be using a JLabel and when should I be using a JPanel?

//I know that you can put JLabels inside a JPanel, and by accident, that a JPanel is more expensive than a JLabel. I, in the long run, plan on making a cashier game that involves some lightweight container for the "money" that moves to the customer's hand upon clicking. I was thinking about using JLabels for the monetary amounts (dollar bills and coins), and the JPanel to serve as the overhead view of the transaction(s). I was also thinking about invoking repaint() (which, to my understanding, can simulate animation) on the "money labels" themselves. This is a double-question, but would you see this as the least expensive way to go about it?

Comment: In general a JPanel is used as a Container. You add components (JLabel, JTextField, JTable, JButton, etc) to the panel and add the panel to the frame. You use multiple panels as needed. Maybe to help with the layout of the GIU.

Comment: You should only use a `JFrame` or `JDialog` (or other top level container) to display other containers (like `JPanel`).  You should endeavor to use `JPanel` as your base line container for all your forms, nesting other panels and controls into as you see fit.  This allows you the flexibility to show your panel/form in any top level container you like.

Comment: I presume the primary reason for this is that JLabels are designed primarily to be just that: labels. They are usable as containers, and have repaint(), paintComponent(), but problems could arise if you were to try to label the stuff in the container (the JLabel!) by giving the JLabel constructor the String argument that is the text to describe what's in there. A JPanel, on the other hand, is a Panel, a designated part of the GUI. Given that it is a distinct part, it is naturally a Container, and should thus be given the stuff. It's all making sense now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the most part, JPanel is a container that allows for better organization. When you need to organize your components of your gui, you should use a JPanel and define a layout for the JPanel. You can also nest JPanels within each other and etc. JLabels don't have the capability of defining layouts for further components to be displayed inside the JLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a app that says "Hello World!!!" without the quotes:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;        
import javax.swing.JPanel;        
import javax.swing.JLabel;        
public class JFrame {        
    public static void main (strings args[]) {        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        String title = "Hello App";        
        frame.setTitle(title);        
        frame.setSize(300, 200);        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation        
            (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        frame.setVisible(true);        
        JPanel panle = new JPanel();        
        frame.add(panle);        
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("Hello World!!!");        
        panle.add(lable);        
    }
}
```

The file name is "JFrame.java" without the quotes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question fully, can you expand?

Comment: And why did you name the class JFrame? Doesn't that already cause problems?